# jQuery UI Datepicker: how to trigger onChangeMonthYear on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'd like to have my `onChangeMonthYear` event triggered when the document is ready.

The only solution I've found so far is the following:

```
$(function() {
    var $element = $('#datepicker');
    var date = new Date();
    var onChangeMonthYear = $element.datepicker("option", "onChangeMonthYear");
    onChangeMonthYear(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, $element);
});
```

But that looks a bit overkill for such a simple requirement.
Anyone with a simpler solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do, move to the next month when the datepicker opens?

Comment: onChangeMonthYear is fired when you change the month in the calendar, but I'd like it to be fired (with the current month/year) when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a function and call it from within both `beforeShow` and `onChangeMonthYear` something like so: (untested)

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        var datePicked = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        doMyStuff(datePicked.getYear(),datePicked.getMonth(), inst); 
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        doMyStuff(year,month, inst);                        
    }
});
```